# Возможно ли анимировать смену состояния?

Tags: reactjs

Делаю компонент по заполнению шкалы (код далеко не идеален, не до этого пока что):

App.js

```
   import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";


export default function App() {
  const [chanels, setChanels] = React.useState([
    {
      name: "chanel1",
      color: "blue",
      memoryPercent: 30
    },{
      name: "chanel2",
      color: "grey",
      memoryPercent: 70
    }]
  )
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="scale">
        {chanels.map(chanel => 
          <div 
          style={{
            background: chanel.color, 
            width: `${chanel.memoryPecent}%`
          }}>
            {chanel.name}
          </div>
          )}
      </div>
      <button>+</button>
      chanel1
      <button>-</button>
      <button>+</button>
      chanel2
      <button>-</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

style.css:

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.scale {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
}
```

Суть следующая:

По нажатию на +/- происходит смена диапазона у нужного канала и данные о смененном диапазоне отправляются на сервер. На сервере происходит перерасчет занимаемого диапазона у каналов и обновленный объект оправляется обратно на клиент.

Вопрос:

Реально ли анимировать изменение ширины каждого канала в зависимости от данных которые пришли с сервера? Например:

Сейчас `memoryPercent` у `chanel1 = 30`%, после того как я отправил запрос на увеличение диапазона у `chanel1` - я получил с сервера обновленный объект: `memoryPercent` у `chanel1` стал равен `40`, а у `chanel2 = 60`.
Или разумнее анимировать это все с помощью данных которые уже есть в `state`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мда, вопрос писал дольше чем искал решение.
`transition: "all 1s"` в `style` добавил.